# Textview size influence size of tablerow

Tags: android, grid, textview, android-tablelayout

I'm new in android development and i have problem tablelayout.

As a practice, i try to make 3x3 table with tablelayout and tablerows in which are one textview.

TableLayout has weightsum 3, inside tablelayout are 3 tablerows with layout_weight 1 and weightsum 3 too. Inside tablerow is only textview.

Problem is that when i try to change size of just one textview, so 8 others textview has same size and one has bigger or smaller size, it will influence whole size of row. How can i avoid this?

```
  <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/wipe_table_layout"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#914949"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#914949"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#914949"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#914949"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView18"
                android:background="#914949"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="35sp"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:password="false"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView19"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#914949"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView20"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#914949"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView21"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#914949"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView22"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#914949"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Preview : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Peet.png